# Set Word-wrap on as default in DBeaver

Tags: word-wrap, dbeaver

I want to have word-wrap on by default in Dbeaver.

There is an answer showing how to toggle word-wrap, but I don't want to do it each time I open Dbeaver :-)

Comment: Look at the comments from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861559/11443568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `wordwrap.enabled=true` in the below file:

Windows:

```
%APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

MacOS: `~/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`

Linux: `$XDG_DATA_HOME/DBeaverData/workspace6/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`

thanks @Reddy Lutonadio

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect "Value" panel?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1774

It should be set in two places:

1. Sets word wrap for the "Value" panel when inspecting rows etc.

Workspace location: DBeaverData/workspace6/.metadata/.plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.data/dialog_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section name="Workbench">
  <section name="AbstractTextPanelEditor">
    <item key="content.text.editor.auto-format" value="true"/>
    <item key="content.text.editor.word-wrap" value="true"/>
  </section>
</section>
```

2. Sets word wrap for the Script/editor panel:

Add the following to the end of the file: Workspace location: DBeaverData/workspace6/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

```
lineNumberRuler=true
wordwrap.enabled=true
```

Note: make sure DBeaver is closed before editing these files.

I tested it and it works.